# How to make Vue js directive working in an appended html element

Tags: vue.js

I have a Vue directive added in an appended html element like v-on directive but it's not working on my end. Basically I want to know the equivalent of .on() in jquery.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

"Vue.js compilation happens when you instantiate/mount the root instance. It doesn't detect new DOM being injected unless it is a result of a directive (e.g. v-repeat, v-partial will dynamically create new DOM fragments)."
https://github.com/vuejs/Discussion/issues/77

You have to compile your newly added element like this:

html:

```
<div id="app">
    <button v-on="click: addNewElement()">Add Element</button> 
    <br />
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        sampleElement: '<button v-on="click: test()">Test</button>'
    },
    methods:{
        addNewElement: function(){
    
           var element = $('#app').append(this.sampleElement);
           /* compile the new content so that vue can read it */
           this.$compile(element.get(0));
        },
        test: function(){
           alert('Test');
        }
    }
});
```

See this working Fiddle <strike>on Firefox:</strike> http://jsfiddle.net/chrislandeza/syewmx4e/

**Update**

$compile has been removed on **Vue 2.x**

I've seen people suggesting **[Vue.compile](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-compile)** or

```
var tmp = Vue.extend({ 
    template: 'Content'
})
new tmp().$mount(' id or refs ')
```

But those 2 does not behave like the old **$compile**.

Comment: @Alexandros Because I was using raw github on my fiddle's external resource. I just fixed that and updated my answer. Sorry for that.

Comment: Sadly, it does not work any more with new vue version. Firstly, syntax has changed for click event. Secondly, there's no "$compile" function any more (probably renamed). If you remove compile and fix syntax, add button works but new buttons do nothing.

Answer (score 11):

For Vue 2.x, the new solution is referenced here in the doc : https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-mount (see 'Example').

Custom example :

```js
var MyComponent = Vue.extend({
  template: '<div v-on:click="world">Hello!</div>',
  methods : {
    world : function() {
      console.log('world')
    }
  }
})
 
var component = new MyComponent().$mount()
document.getElementById('app').appendChild(component.$el)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

You need to register the html as a template of the component.