# Vue bind after AJAX partial loads?

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel-5.1, vue.js

I am just getting started with Vue.js and trying to incorporate it into an app I've been building for a while. My app is built using Laravel, a fair amount of jQuery, etc.

All of my navigation elements in my app are using AJAX (not via Vue) to return partial views. So any internal link or form submission is submitted via AJAX to a Laravel route that returns a partial.

I have set up my first Vue instance but it only binds to the element the first time the visitor hits the page where the Vue instance is used. The Vue instance still exists but it looses it's binding to the element when the user navigates away from the page and then comes back -- presumably because the element has been removed from the DOM when the user navigated away.

How do I get Vue to bind back to the element when it returns to the DOM (via an AJAX load that isn't performed by Vue)?

My main.js (consumed by Elixir / Browserify):

```
window.MaintenanceStatus = require('./components/Status.js');
```

Status.js

```
var Vue = require('vue');
Vue.use(require('vue-resource'));

module.exports = new Vue({
    el: '#app',

    data: {
        message: ''
    },

    ready: function() {
        this.message = 'loading ...';
    },

    methods: {
        setMessage: function(message) {
            this.message = message;
        },

        getStatus: function(url, data) {
            this.message = 'loading ...';
            this.$http.get(url, data)
                .success(function(result) {
                    console.log('Status get success');
                    this.setMessage(result);
                })
                .error(function() {
                    console.log('Status get error');
                    this.setMessage('Error');
                });
        }
    }
});
```

The consuming code which is a partial/template that is returned via AJAX ...

```
@extends('layouts.partials.content')


@section('content')
    <div id="app">
        <pre>@{{ $data | json }}</pre>
    </div>
@stop

@section('javascript')
<script type="text/javascript" class="document-script">
$(function()
{
    var href ...
    var data {...}

    MaintenanceStatus.getStatus(href, data);
});
</script>
@stop
```

Note that it works on a full page refresh but if I navigate to another page (again that's an AJAX call) then I return back to this view, I just see {{ $data | json }} ... Vue seems to have lost it's binding to the app element. How do I get it back?

I tried binding the Vue instance to an element that does not ever leave the DOM and then created a component but I get the same result ... the component renders on a full page refresh but not when the partial is loaded via AJAX.

I also tried messing around with .$mount, but that had no effect.

Comment: Try re-compiling your vue instance after your ajax call and when the partial finished loading, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30546370/how-to-make-vue-js-directive-working-in-an-appended-html-element/32757950#32757950

Answer (score 4):

I recommend you taking a look at the `activate` hook [here](http://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#activate_Hook).

From the Doc:

```
component = {
  activate: function (done) {
    var self = this
    loadDataAsync(function (data) {
      self.someData = data
      done()
    })
}
```

Basically call `done()` when the data is ready. The component will be then inserted

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of one way to do what you want, but I believe this is not recommended by the creator of Vue:

parent vue instance declaration:

```
window.vm = new Vue({...})
```

This part could be in the success function of your ajax call:

```
var newContent = $(response.new_content_html).wrap('<div></div>');

$('#some-container-for-the-dynamic-content').html(newContent);
var newContentInstance = window.vm.$addChild({ 
     el: '#some-container-for-the-dynamic-content', 
     data: function data() {
          return { emptyRecordData: {} };
     } 
});
newContentInstance.$mount();
newContentInstance.$data.someOtherData = response.some_other_data;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working by changing my Status.js to return a closure:

```
module.exports = function() { return new Vue({...}) }
```

And in the script portion of the partial that gets returned via ajax I'm able to create a new instance:

```
var MaintenanceStatus = window.MaintenanceStatus();

...

MaintenanceStatus.getStatus(href, data);
```