# Are dynamic arguments in Vue.js templates possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

Here is my setup, and I know its not ideal (I inherited this project from a couple of developers that are no longer working on this web app). I'm trying to marry Vue.js and JQuery so that I can simply re-use JQuery based components (instead of rewriting them) on my Vue.js page (the two previous developers having design differences).

What I need is this: I am filling a table with components post page Mount. Everything about this table populates correctly except I have buttons in some of the cells in which I would like to use Vue.js to operate those buttons' functionality. I can add a `v-on:click=` attribute just fine but since these attributes are added to the buttons post Mount their Vue attributes are not being listened to. On the client side (Edge/Chrome in this case) I can see the vue attributes in the developers console when inspecting the element. I looked up examples such as this article:
[How to make Vue js directive working in an appended html element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30546370/how-to-make-vue-js-directive-working-in-an-appended-html-element) regarding how to correctly re-render components after they are appended post Mount. Since these objects were created and appended to the web page after mounting they are not Reactive.

The article suggests creating a component that can then be mounted manually, using a template to create the component. I've tried this and found that using `Vue.extend` to create a new subclass/component now disallows me to access methods in my original app. Let me place some code and then I'll recap:

**What I see on the client side console:**

```
<button type="button" class="results_table_col_1_button" v-on:click="test()">200-715-122-306-ATP</button>
```

**How the data table is being updated via JQUERY**

```
        display_search_results: function (data) {
            data = JSON.parse(data);
            let num = data.row_order.length;
            if (num > 0) {
                displayDataTable(data);
                $("#tableContainer").show();
                $("#test_count").text(num + " test" + (num === 1 ? '' : 's') + " found");
        
                $('#dataDisplayTable tr').not(':first').each(function (i, el) {
                    let save_id = $(el).find('td.results_table_col_1').text()
                    $(el).find('button.results_table_col_1_button').attr("v-on:click", 'test()')
```

**What I tried via the article**

```
//How the new component is being created:
var testComp = new ATP_Button().$mount()
document.getElementsByClassName("results_table_col_1")[i].appendChild(testComp.$el)

//with the constructor:
var ATP_Button = Vue.extend({
    template: '<button type="button" v-on:click="test()">Is this working</button>',
})
```

This creates the button but test is then undefined as it is not initialized or referenced to in the subclass object ATP_Button. How do I pass my 'main' Vue app's test() function to this component so that when the button $emits its event the parent's test() function is called?

I also tried adding props to the constructor so that I could maybe pass test() into the component upon creation like this:

```
var ATP_Button = Vue.extend({
    props: ['test'],
    template: '<button type="button" v-on:click="test_child()">Is this working</button>',
    methods: {
        test_child: function () {
            this.test
            alert(this.test)
        }
    }

})
```

And created the component as such:

```
var testComp = new ATP_Button(this.test_func).$mount()
```

Now however this.test inside the component is undefined as it would seem that passing the function through is not working properly (probably due to developer error aka me).

**RECAP**

- A JQUERY table object is being populated via a backend process with HTML elements to be displayed on the front end view of the webpage
- One element that is added is a button that needs to be able to call a Vue.js method from the main app
- The elements are added to the table after the page has been mounted thus they are not reactive
- Trying to manually mount the component creates a subclass object that does not have access to the main app's methods
- Trying to pass the main app's method test() to the component during construction failed and left the test variable undefined
- Eventually I need the buttons to call a method from the main app with dynamic variables inside as arguments

I appreciate anyone who is able to offer any assistance.

Comment: If your vue app is created with `new Vue({` then alias it to a variable and bind it to the window `window.vm = new Vue({` and then call `window.vm.test()`

Comment: That was embarrassingly simple. I already had my vue app named: plotterApp so yes; plotterApp.test() worked. Now I'll use props to send in the variables on construction and use plotterApp.test(someVariable).

Thank you Ohgodwhy (not to mention your name personifies my feelings now)